# How to connect two different database tables using laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-routing

I am currently pulling data from a table. That table is helping me display client data and display it using `{{ DATA HERE}}` within a blade file.

However, I have another table with a different Primary ID KEY I need to connect to the client data.

The client data has a primary ID called `companyID` and the other table has `ruleID`.

They share `companyname` and `MainID` but Table to has a different primary.

Lets say for example:

Table One:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mainID | statusname | companyname data data |

Table Two:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ruleID | mainID | companyname data data |

How do I mix these tables? I am having a hard time explaining this since I am new and I may not be using the correct terms so please be patient.

Comment: More clearly, do you want to get information about the company the client belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you used Eloquent like this:

```php
class Client extends Model {
    public function main()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Main::class, 'company_name', 'name');
    }

    public function rule()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Rule::class, 'company_name', 'name');
    }
}
```

```php
class Main extends Model {
    public function rule()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Rule::class);
    }

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'name', 'company_name');
    }
}
```

```php
class Rule extends Model {
    public function main()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Main::class);
    }

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'name', 'company_name');
    }
}
```